# Invalid Username or Password, but cannot try a different one

Tags: git, git-remote

Good evening. I've been having an issue with git, and though I've asked elsewhere they weren't able to help me. This is my first time using it, so odds are good I've done something stupid somewhere.

## Problem

In class, we're supposed to use a git repository for a group project. One was made per group, and in order to even get a grade it is required we commit our code.

As such, I installed git and went through the tutorial the official site offered on how to use it.
After that, I tried to connect to the repository the school offered us by using the command

```
git remote add test https://url
```

and, once prompted, entered the password I thought I was being asked for. However, a popup told me this was the wrong password.

I then tried logging into the site where we can see our repositories, with the same account details, and it did work.

I figured I'd typed something wrong, and tried again, but this time I never got the prompt for the password. I was stuck with the (presumably) wrong password.

## Attempted solutions

I tried different commands, like

```
 git clone url
```

I've tried using a GUI (SourceTree) a friend recommended to me, but it too never asked for a password to that repository. I'm fairly sure I've got the right URL, at least.

The authentication seems to be HTTP. My reason for thinking so is that nowhere on the site SSH keys are given.

Thanks in advance for helping me.

Comment: You're not having those square brackets on the command literally, do you?

Comment: What is the output of `git config credential` ? If you see your (bad) password, read the [gitcredentials documentation](https://git-scm.com/docs/gitcredentials).

Comment: No, I don't have the brackets on there literally. The output of git config credential is "error: key does not contain a section: credential".

Comment: You probably need to generate a key and upload it to the website under your profile

Comment: I've generated a SSH key now, but I don't see anywhere on the site that allows me to upload a key. I'm still getting the same invalid username/password error, too.

Answer (score 0):

If you have added `remote` successfully, then try to push your files using

```
git push
```

and it will ask you again to enter your credentials (username & password).
Here you can enter your correct username & password again.